# Unable to Navigate to ASMX

Tags: permissions, web-services, administration

I've created a custom webservice and I have deployed it to the server (ISAPI), it shows up as a webservice on my local machine when I try to select a web reference from Visual Studio.

However I can't click on it and view/invoke the method.
At first it said the file type was blocked by Administrators, so I removed the ASMX extension from the list of blocked file types.

Now when I visit `http://mysite:1339/myservice.asmx` it just gives me the generic error "Cannot complete this action"

or "An error has occurred on the server" if I try to browse to the file from IIS.

I have made sure that my account has full control permissions across all of my sharepoint websites but still the error persists.
Can anyone point me in the right direction? These error message are very uninformative! :(

Edit:
I didn't notice this before but it was happening before I changed the reference to `RWL01's` suggestion. I am getting a type error in the URL parameters but looks like the page doesn't serve the error message up exactly right.

`http://mysite:1339/_layouts/error.aspx?ErrorText=Could%20not%20create%20type%20%27%24SharePoint%2EProject%2EAssemblyFullName%24%27%2E`

Comment: A note for future readers, using custom web services on Sharepoint is a crap idea and it makes everything a little harder and in 99% of cases not needed. As the current WebServices (with Frontpage RPC for somethings) can do pretty much anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ran into a similar issue.

I used **$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$** to reference my assembly. This works fine except for .asmx files.

I had to modify they Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.targets file in my development environment for this to work. I did this by going to:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\SharePointTools
- Searched for "`<TokenReplacementFileExtensions>`"
- Added ";asmx" to the list

Comment: You searched for what? Its not clear to me what values you are changing in `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Sharepoint.targets`

Comment: Sorry about that I had tags in there that got removed. I was searching for TokenReplacementFileExtensions.

Comment: Thanks, I thought this was a great way to get the full class name.